# max value in JavaScript multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

im taking my first steps with angular and came across this problem. i have this array :

```
var users = [{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'John',
    'score': '46',
    'difference': 'diff from top'
},{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'Harry',
    'score': '45',
    'difference': 'diff from top'
},{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'Sam',
    'score': '43',
    'difference': 'diff from top'
}];
```

and i want to get the highest score and store it in a variable (in this case - 46). how can i do that?? im looking for as much "angularish" solution as possible

Comment: Why use angular just to use it? I'd imagine you would want to use vanilla javascript as much as possible before using frameworks to do things, simple things too, such as looping through this array. Also, why does your id not have quotes around it?

Comment: obviously, my app will do more than just that (hopefully) and the all purpose of this app its to learn angular

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

Initially, we define a function for finding the max score.

```
function getHighestScore(array) {
    var max;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].score > (max || 0))
            max = array[i].score;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then we pass the array of the users to it and get the max score.

```
var maxScore = getHighestScore(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner. This won't work in all browsers because of the map function :

```
Math.max.apply(null, users.map(function(elem) { return +elem.score;}))
```